# Dialog box without title

Tags: android, android-dialog

I need to delete the title in a dialog. Note i dont need a blank title.I need to delete the title section.Following is my code:

```
final Dialog dialog1=new Dialog(context);
    dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.redeemvoucher_first);
    dialog1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog1.getWindow().setLayout(900,500);
        dialog1.show();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this while creating dialog

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Before calling `setContentView`, add this to remove the title:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it meets your needs so that others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
Dialog dialog1=new Dialog(context)
```

with:

```
Dialog dialog1=new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
```